# What is an example to execute callback once user has responded

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

Below is the handler method in the CefSharp Example ([link](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/dcff3d009427e88582db43e2927202d55d23ba3b/CefSharp.Example/JsDialogHandler.cs)) for OnBeforeUnloadDialog. What does it mean by **execute callback once user has responded**?

```
        bool IJsDialogHandler.OnBeforeUnloadDialog(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, string message, bool isReload, IJsDialogCallback callback)
    {
        //Custom implementation would look something like
        // - Create/Show dialog on UI Thread
        // - execute callback once user has responded
        // - callback.Continue(true);
        // - return true

        //NOTE: Returning false will trigger the default behaviour, no need to execute the callback if you return false.
        return false;
```

}

Comment: Am i supposed to have an implementation of IJsDialogCallback ??

Comment: Display your custom dialog/form to the user, once they're selected yes/no then execute the callback (which is the last param of the method). It's important to note the example code you are referencing is only valid for the current `master` branch, each release has it's own branch see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp#release-branches

Comment: API docs are at http://cefsharp.github.io/api/

Comment: I hate to admit it, but I just don't understand what is meant by "execute the callback". If you could pop in a little C# that'd help me a ton to better understand this key concept.

Comment: The example is in the code already, the `API` doc is http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IJsDialogCallback_Continue.htm

Comment: @amaitland could you please provide a link to the code?

Comment: It's in the code above, `callback.Continue(true);`